# Plot netcdf file with matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, netcdf

I want to plot a netcdf file in matlab that I have already analyze it as a .mat archive.
 I have to plot it with a map background with coastlines and degrees of longitude and latitude I want. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could plot your data on a map using the m_map package found [here](http://www.eos.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html). There's also examples there for reading in netcdf and hdf5 data and using .mat archive should then be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I find m_map very useful. Hope help me for all plots i need. If i have any question i will ask your help again.

Comment: Trond when i plot a .mat file how can i show the degrees on it's axis x,y?

Comment: Yes, ok but sorry i don't know how to accept an answer. Sorry i am new in forum

Comment: @SotirisTsiougkos When you plot the longitude-latitude the degrees should show automatically if you follow any of these examples: http://www.eos.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html#7._Lambert_Conformal_Projection_with_Med. If you only have x,y values you need to convert these to longitude-latitude.

Comment: Kristansen i think i make something wrong with these 3 steps; m_proj('lambert','lon',[-10 20],'lat',[33 48]);
m_tbase('contourf');
m_grid('linestyle','none','tickdir','out','linewidth',3);      My m_mat file called ''v''.   How have i to write these steps?  Really thank you

Comment: You need to create arrays for lon and lat based on the values you have in your v matrix

Comment: my .mat file is a numeric array. Could you explain or give an example of what do you mean?

Comment: Dimensions:
           longitude = 961
           latitude  = 961
           time      = 1     (UNLIMITED)
Variables:
    v
           Size:       961x961x1
           Dimensions: longitude,latitude,time
           Datatype:   int16

Comment: This is the result (ncdisp) of my .mat file

Comment: It is difficult to help you with your problem. I think you need to read up on using basic Matlab matrixes and how to use NetCDF. You can extract the longitude and latitude most likely as vectors from your file. Then you extract the 2D matrix of values and plot longitude,latitude, and your values using m_map.

Comment: I have extract my Netcdf file into a 2d matrix with lon and lat on 2 axis with the values of v. My problem is after this using m_map. For this i ask you a mini example Trond

Comment: My problem is that my Netcdf files are 0,25*0,25. As you can understand every 4 values in my .mat file is 1 degree for lon and lat

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question on SO where you describe your dataset and your problems and what you have tried so far. It should be straightforward creating a vector of longitude and latitude when you know the resolution of your dataset including your start and end values. Once you have a vector for lon and lat use the examples in m_map to plot.